# Remove intersecting geometry for 3d printing?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

just wondering if there's an easy way to remove intersecting geometry so I can have it ready for 3d printing?

I have pipes intersecting in my mesh (amongst other things) as you can see in the bottom picture if I hide the closest face. I tried this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kf16s5MPBLg but it's pretty old and doesn't work even if using the Boolean "Exact" solver and turning on the "self" checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Is overlapping geometry really a problem for 3d printing? At least for FDM printing intersecting solid geometry without holes and with correct normals is [not a problem](https://i.postimg.cc/sDbn76dw/image.png).

Comment: yeah this is for resin printing that needs to be hollowed out